# How to change Eclipse IDE Title Bar

Tags: eclipse, font-face, font-size, eclipse-jee

How can I change the font size and style of red underlined 1 and 2 of Eclipse IDE in the image given below?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The window title is rendered by the operating system, so it's an operating system setting ([in your case it looks like Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/952395))
2. In *Window > **Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*** change the ***View and Editor Folders > Part title font***

Comment: The window title font size in my Eclipse IDE keeps changing automatically. Sometimes it opens with font size 9, sometimes it opens with size 10. What could be causing this?

Comment: You're talking about 1, right? This is an operating system thing. I have never observed what you describe, although I use different versions of Eclipse a lot. Maybe it's active window vs. window in the background.

Comment: I could fix the Eclipse IDE's Title Bar using "Winaero Tweaker" at https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-reduce-title-bar-height-and-size-of-window-buttons-in-windows-10. It fixed my Sublime Text's Title Bar as well.

Comment: This is not correct (or no longer correct) The Part title font is not the window title.

Comment: @DonaldWinston Sure, 1 (window title) and 2 (part title) are different things: 1. refers to the window title which is rendered by the operating system and 2. refers to the view and editor (= part) title.